# Removing(unregistering) a section from django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin, internal-server-error, attributeerror, django-admin-actions

From the django admin page, I wanted to remove a section of an app. At first, the admin.py had this contents:

```
admin.site.register(MyUser)
```

So I changed it to be:

```
admin.site.unregister(MyUser)
```

and it caused Internal Server Error.

What should I do to remove the section of account app from the admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't register you model in `admin.py` and it will be "removed" from admin page.  Comment or delete this line instead of changing it:

```
# admin.site.register(MyUser)
```

Comment: OMG I spent so many hours trying to solve this silly issue... Thank you so much!